# perf record with --call-stack fp fails to unwind main function

Tags: c++, glibc, libc, perf, stack-unwinding

I have a C++ test program that keeps the CPU busy:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

// Linear-feedback shift register
uint64_t lfsr1(uint64_t max_ix)
{
    uint64_t start_state = 0xACE1u;  /* Any nonzero start state will work. */
    uint64_t lfsr = start_state;
    uint64_t bit;                    /* Must be 16-bit to allow bit<<15 later in the code */

    for (uint64_t ix = 0; ix < max_ix; ++ix)
    {   /* taps: 16 14 13 11; feedback polynomial: x^16 + x^14 + x^13 + x^11 + 1 */
        bit = ((lfsr >> 0) ^ (lfsr >> 1) ^ (lfsr >> 3) ^ (lfsr >> 4)) & 1 /* & 1u */;
        lfsr = (lfsr >> 1) | (bit << 15);
    }
    return lfsr;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << lfsr1(1717986914ull) << "\n";
}
```

I compile it with `g++ -g -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer cpu.cpp -o cpu.bin`, then run it with `perf record -F 100 --call-graph fp -- ./cpu.bin` and a second time with `dwarf` instead of `fp`.

In the `perf script` output for `fp`, I can see

```
cpu.bin 23435 1535437.021156:   42706947 cycles: 
            5617daf4b7a1 main+0x31 (…/cpu.bin)
            7f9a95088bf7 __libc_start_main+0xe7 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so)
         3fe258d4c544155 [unknown] ([unknown])
```

whereas for `dwarf`, it's

```
cpu.bin 23443 1535441.101859:   42952079 cycles: 
            55a3b4ffd7a1 lfsr1+0x31 (inlined)
            55a3b4ffd7a1 main+0x31 (…/cpu.bin)
            7f00bcc8ebf6 __libc_start_main+0xe6 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so)
            55a3b4ffd829 _start+0x29 (…/cpu.bin)
```

Seems like perhaps `fp` is off by one byte in `__libc_start_main` and that causes it to miss the last unwind step. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I guess this is because lfsr1 is inlined (`lfsr1+0x31 (inlined)` in dwarf report). You can maybe try to declare it with `__attribute__((noinline))`.

Comment: @dewaffled I'm interested in the missing `_start` frame, not the missing `lsfr1` frame.

Comment: Is `__libc_start_main` compiled to use a traditional frame-pointer in your (distro's) build of glibc?  I wouldn't be surprised if libc is compiled normally (`-O2` *without* `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`), including that file, and probably that function doesn't have any special override for that.

Comment: Probably yes. When I try on Ubuntu 20.04 instead of 18.04, I get no more `[unknown]`, but no `_start` either. But when I install libc6-prof and use that, `_start` is there, and backtraces from libc functions work much better overall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Peter said in his comment, the problem resolves itself when a version of glibc with frame pointers is used. On Ubuntu 20.04, there is a package with such a glibc.

```
sudo apt install libc6-prof
# To use this library:
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/libc6-prof/x86_64-linux-gnu perf record …
```

Then, the `[unknown]` is resolved to `_start` as expected.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1908307